# how to add Facebook's pixel into Google's AMP?

Tags: html, google-analytics, amp-html, facebook-pixel, google-amp

For the time being, it appears that no one at Facebook nor Google have added Facebook tracking pixel into [amp-analytics](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/analytics/analytics-vendors) yet.

Does anybody here knows how to do it ? sample code or github is preferred.

thank you very much

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work

```
<amp-pixel src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=YOUR_ID&ev=PageView&noscript=1" 
    layout="nodisplay"></amp-pixel>
```

You will need to change `YOUR_ID` to the ID you can find in Facebook's tracking code.

I created this by adopting the noscript src from their sample script for use in amp-pixel. More advanced usages would be possible, but ideally Facebook would provide the respective documentation.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be the recommended way from amp documentation.

Answer (score 9):

It seems support was added on [June 6, 2017](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/pull/9449). You can do:

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Analytics tracking -->
<amp-analytics type="facebookpixel" id="facebook-pixel">
    <script type="application/json">
    {
        "vars": {
            "pixelId": "YOUR_ID"
        },
        "triggers": {
            "trackPageview": {
                "on": "visible",
                "request": "pageview"
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
</amp-analytics>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Analytics example -->
```

The documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/91c2752b405a516e52bef70b58e7c17511202663/examples/analytics-vendors.amp.html#L672).